# How to realize automatic type conversion for template methods?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I am using self-written template methods to load and save settings from/into Qt's `QSettings`. `QSettings` receive/return data of type `QVariant` and `QVariant` has constructors taking basic types like `int` and `double`, but **not** `std::string`.

My template method can therefore easily be used for `int` and `double`, but when using `std::string` I get compile error messages that there is no matching function call, because there is no known conversion from `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` to the types accepted by `QVariant`'s constructors.

Of course I can solve the problem by writing a specialization of my template method. Still, I am hesitating to do that, because there is exactly **one** little call that causes the problem. The rest of the code is just fine for all types.

Is it possible to provide a user-defined type conversion such that the compiler can automatically use for type-conversion when compiling the template method?

Here is a minimal example that tries to reproduce the situation without Qt classes:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:

    A(int)
    {
    }

    A(double)
    {
    }
};

std::vector<A> globalStorage;

template <typename Type>
void store(Type element)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...
    //

    // Final Storage
    globalStorage.push_back(A(element));
}

// TODO: A specialization of the template method solves the problem. Is there
// another way to provide a user-defined type conversion?
template <>
void store<std::string>(std::string element)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...
    //

    globalStorage.push_back(A(std::stoi(element)));
}

int main()
{
    double number1 = 1.0;
    int number2 = 2.0;
    float number3 = 3.0;

    store (number1);
    store (number2);
    store (number3);

    std::string number4 = "4";
    store(number4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note `QVariant` does have constructors from `const char*` (which assumes UTF-8) and from `QString`. It would probably be simplest to just use `.c_str()` or do a proper conversion to `QString` in the code which uses your template.

Comment: @aschepler You are right, but is there a possibility to make such a conversion happen without writing a specialized template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an overloaded non-template for `std::string` that forwards to your method.

```
template <typename Type>
void store(Type element)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...
    //

    // Final Storage
    globalStorage.push_back(A(element));
}

void store(const std::string& s) {
    //convert s to QString or char* or a number, as you want
    auto converted_element = ...;
    store(converted_element);
}
```

Comment: Your idea is nice. It indeed solves the example problem in a nice way. Still I wonder whether there is a possibility to tell the C++ compiler how to do arbitrary type conversions. I will post another question...

Comment: The proposal of this answer works less well if for example a whole container needs to be converted. Here is a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828520/can-i-tell-the-c-compiler-how-to-do-arbitrary-type-conversions. It demonstrates the disadvantages of this (good) answer.