# Can I tell the C++ compiler how to do arbitrary type conversions itself?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

This question is a follow-up of another question: [How to realize automatic type conversion for template methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817890/how-to-realize-automatic-type-conversion-for-template-methods/60818202?noredirect=1#comment107610640_60818202).

If a type conversion is needed within a template method, can I somehow tell the compiler how to do just that conversion itself?

I know two possibilities to code the conversion:

- template specialization
- providing a conversion overload (which has been the answer of the former question).

Both are fine, but may require writing boilerplate code. Is there a way to "inject" just the type conversion code and let the compiler do the rest?

Please see the following example code. I need to provide a conversion from `std::string` to my `Setting` class. How could I tell the compiler how to convert it?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Setting
{
public:

    Setting(int)
    {
    }

    Setting(double)
    {
    }

    // It is not possible to provide a constructor taking std::string as argument,
    // because this code is within an external libary!!!
};

// Is is not possible to create an overload of this method, since in real life
// it is a class member function within an external library.
//
void storeSetting(const Setting&)
{
    // Storing setting...
}

// Template method that works with int, double and float, because Settings can
// be created from these basic types. But the method will not work
// for std::string, since there is no appropriate constructor.
template <typename Type>
void storeAll(std::vector<Type> elements)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...
    //

    // Final Storage
    for (const Type& element : elements)
    {
        storeSetting(element);
    }
}

// Solution by template specialization
template <>
void storeAll(std::vector<std::string> elements)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...
    //

    // Final Storage
    for (const std::string& element : elements)
    {
        storeSetting(stoi(element));
    }
}

// Solution by providing a conversion overload
//
// TODO: When containers are concerned, this is not handy.
// I dont have to repeat the "lengthy storage preparation code".
// On the other hand, the conversion code is lengthy boilerplate code itself.
// Is there another way to "inject" a user-defined type conversion?
void storeAll(std::vector<std::string> elements)
{
    std::vector<int> convertedElements;

    for (const std::string& element : elements)
    {
        convertedElements.push_back(stoi(element));
    }

    storeAll(convertedElements);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> numbers1 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    std::vector<int> numbers2 = {2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<float> numbers3 = {3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

    storeAll(numbers1);
    storeAll(numbers2);
    storeAll(numbers3);

    std::vector<std::string> numbers4 = {"4", "5", "6"};
    storeAll(numbers4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"writing boilerplate code"*. Mostly true as you did it at the wrong level: `void storeSetting(const std::string& s) { storeSetting(Setting(stoi(s))); }`. Or even a `makeSetting` overloads set.

Comment: @Jarod42 This is the disadvange of creating minimal examples. ;) In my real-life code the counterpart of `storeSetting` is also part of the third-part library which cannot be modified (it's a class member function). I will modify my question...

Comment: @Jarod42 Of course your comment is perfectly right as far as the original example code is concerned... I realize that I have imposed many restrictions on the possible solution. Probably there is none... is there?

Comment: You can always replace all your calls to `storeSetting` with calls to `myStoreSetting` and give your wrapper overloads to deal with the conversion.

Comment: If you can change `storeAll`, you might use something like `storeSetting(makeSetting(element));` to handle extra conversions.

Comment: As a matter of style, [avoid specializing function templates](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-specialize-function). The fact that specialization is possible here is little more than a technical curiosity. For real world code you will almost certainly want to use overloads exclusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add implicit conversion between types you don't own.

But you can still create function which does the conversion for you:

```
// The forwarding one for exisiting contructor
template <typename ... Ts>
auto makeSetting(const Ts&... args)
-> decltype(Setting{args...})
{
    return Setting{args...};
}

// Optionally, one to avoid unwanted copy constructor
const Setting& makeSetting(const Setting& s) { return s; }

// Your extra version
Setting makeSetting(const std::string& s)
{
    return Setting{std::stoi(s)};
}
```

Then in your generic function:

```
template <typename T>
void storeAll(std::vector<T> elements)
{
    // A lot of lengthy storage preparation code
    // ...

    // Final Storage
    for (const auto& element : elements)
    {
        storeSetting(makeSetting(element));
    }
}
```